LLM not giving same results in CPU but good on GPU
When I tried to ask Mistral to give results back in JSON format, the results were very good on Bedrock .
When I used mistral on ubuntu but on CPU the results were really bad.
Also, on the gpu server stableLM was running, that also gave good results.
Does underlying hardware impacts results?


Does underlying hardware impacts results?

May slightly impacts results, but shouldn't be dramatic. I'd check if the models you ran are the same.
